# PHP preg_replace first word (including special chars)

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a string which would look something like this "1-1-2012 Something, Something"

How could i wrap the date section so the result would end up as `<span>1-1-2012</span> Something, Something`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
list($a,$b) = explode(" ",$input,2);
$out = "<span>".$a."</span> ".$b;
```

Comment: yes, but this assumes the part of up to the first space is always the date. Not saying the solution is bad. Just pointing it out.

Comment: True, but then a regex would have to assume a certain date format.

Comment: If it works well, check this comment as an answer to your question by clicking on the check-mark.

Comment: @MartinAndersson The question had to be 15 minutes old before Blackbird could do that.

Comment: @Blackbird, my only intention was to share knowledge. For a reason unknown today, I thought you were a complete newbie and had no idea about the practice. Anyways, good to know everything worked out okay.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$str = "11-10-2012 Something, Something";
$str = preg_replace("/\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}/", '<span>$0</span>', $str);
var_dump($str);
```

Output

```
 string '<span>4-10-2012</span> Something, Something' (length=43)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace( '~\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}~', '<span>$0</span>', '1-1-2012 Something something' );
```

The regular expression `~\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}` looks for one or two integers, followed by `-`, followed by another one or two integers, followed by a `-`, followed by 4 integers, which matches both "1-1-2012" and "05-10-2012". It then replaces the match with `<span>$0</span>`, where $0 will be replaced with the date found.

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to this otherwise correct answer?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I fail to see how it is not an answer. The OP already knew he wanted to use preg_replace, so he's just looking for the correct syntax. The correct syntax is the answer, so I feel the explanation I've added is rather superfluous.

Answer (score -1):

check this:

```
$str="1-1-2012 Something, Something";
$str=preg_replace('/\d-\d-\d{4}/', '<span>$0</span>', $str);
echo $str;
```

**UPD**

I missed that the first part was date :)

This might be used:

```
$str=preg_replace('/(:?\d{1,2}-){2}\d{4}/', '<span>$0</span>', $str);
```

Comment: What if the date is today's? `5-10-2012`?

Comment: What about 5-10-2012? Lol @Kolink, 5 seconds apart :D